I am unable to upgrade my Expo Version from SDK 49 to SDK 51 and my app just doesn't run
4 months ago, I made an app using React Native which was compatible with Expo SDK 49. Now, I want to improvise my app. When I tried to run it, it showed the following message.
Project is incompatible with this version of Expo Go

The installed version of Expo Go is for SDK 51.
The project you opened uses SDK 49.
How to fix this error
Either upgrade this project to SDK 51, or lauch it in an iOS simulator. It is not possible to install an older version of Expo Go for iOS devices, only the latest version is supported.

I am using an iPhone and I cannot go back to the previous version. When I tried upgrading my app to SDK 51, this happened.
Also, npx expo install --fix doesn't do anything.
These things are outdated in my app.
I have to present my app in 3 weeks but I am not even able to run the app. And I cannot use an iOS simulator as I don't have a Mac. Please help me in upgrading my project to SDK 51.

I would suggest, updating to Expo v50 first and if that succeeds, update to Expo v51

I am not able to do that either.

Try running the following commands:
npm cache verify

npm cache clean --force

rm -rf node_modules/

rm package-lock.json

npm install

npx expo start -c

